# Calculation between Values and Keys in Dictionarys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, finance

I'm trying to perform a calculation between a dictionary value and its respective key.

`dict_cashflows = {0:-10000, 1: 500, 2: 1500, 10: 10000}
 rate=0.06`

For instance, I would like to discount the cash-flows on the dictionary above. It is important to use the dictionary keys to discount values, so I don´t need to fill blank in between keys.

For each pair in the dictionary, the calculation should be:

`value/((1+rate)**key)`

For any doubt, please feel free to ask.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: you can iterate a dictionary with key,value pairs by doing `for key,value in dict_cashflows.items()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either iterate on just the keys, or you can iterate on both:

```
dict_cashflows = {0:-10000, 1: 500, 2: 1500, 10: 10000}
rate=0.06
cashflow = {k : dict_cashflows[k] / (1.+rate)**k for k in dict_cashflows.keys()} #building a new dict from iterating over keys
print(cashflow)
cashflow2 = {k : v / (1.+rate)**k for k,v in dict_cashflows.items()} #building a new dict while iterating on both
print(cashflow2)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, and seems much better to the one I posted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So, this was the way I found to do it:

`dict_cashflows = {0:-10000, 1: 500, 2: 1500, 10: 10000}`

```
   `def NPV_dict(dictcfs,rate=0.06):
    npv=0.0
    periods=list(dictcfs.keys())
    cfs=list(dictcfs.values())
    for i in range(len(dict_cashflows)):
        calc=cfs[i]/((1+rate)**(periods[i]))
        npv+=calc    
    return npv`
```

Comment: Ouch!  `range(len(...))` is a python code smell.  Use `for period, cashflow in dict.items():` instead

Comment: @MartinBonner I just started coding. Thank you for your feedback